# XLConnect: saveworkbook update error

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, xlconnect

`saveWorkbook()` function in XLConnect saves the workbook and the changes and updated calculations are visible in the excel file but not on R (because it has a formula not accepted by the apache poi)

However, to view the cell I save the file to disk and call it using another function. But when I call the same file again the calculated fields still show the old values. I don't want to save the excel file every time I make a change in the workbook.

Would you know a workaround to be able to call the new values without manually saving excel?

Code -

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")
library(rJava)
library(XLConnect)
wb = loadWorkbook(file.choose(), create = TRUE)
readWorksheet(wb,16, region = 'D25:D26')
writeWorksheet(wb,-.45,sheet = 16,startRow = 25,startCol = 4)
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb,sheet = 16, TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
detach("package:XLConnect", unload=TRUE)
detach("package:XLConnectJars", unload=TRUE)
library(xlsx)
y = read.xlsx(file.choose(), sheetIndex = 16)
```

So the Excel file on the system shows the changes corresponding to the new -.45 value but when I read the file again, the calculated values are the old values and not the new ones. This gets fixed if I save the file manually.

Comment: Hi Anuj, can you provide a reproducible example? Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Anuj, please edit your post and paste the code there using the format for code

Comment: Hey I did that, posted here by mistake,

Comment: @Rohit can u help with this?

Comment: Try specifying the file name in the `saveWorkbook` command

Comment: Did that, still no luck

Comment: Have you tried the same with the xlsx package? It has similiar functions

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command you are using is correct but maybe some small modifications would make this work.

I think you could try placing the needed calculations in a different sheet in excel and treat the data you inserted as a dependency for those calculations in the new sheet.

Then read it in as a fresh workbook and call the new sheet. I think that will you the output you need.

```
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, sheet = "*", TRUE)
```

I would use this command to force all sheets to recalculate instead.

Hope that helps!